# Content in between Header/Footer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a site where each page has a `<TopNav>`, `<Footer>` and a `<Subfooter>`.

As I understand it, the entry point of the app, should include these three components, and an additional component/s should render depending on the route the user is on.

I've built my entry point like so:

**App.js**

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <TopNav />
    <Footer />
    <Subfooter />
  </div>
)
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The problem with the way I've structured this is that I can't render anything in between `<TopNav>` & `<Footer>`. Should I do something like this in **App.js** and somehow inject the proper components into `<PageContent>` based on the route?

**App.js**

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <TopNav />
    <PageContent />
    <Footer />
    <Subfooter />
  </div>
)
```

Also, all each component in app requires a router as they all contain `<nav>` - where should I be defining the `<Router>` for all three of these components?

What is the correct approach to adding any necessary component between the three listed in **App.js** - and where  should the routing code go to dictate the behavior for all three of these components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this could be:-

Routes.js

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import SomeComponent from './components/some-component';
import AnotherComponent from './components/another-component';

const taskRouter = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={SomeComponent} />
            <Route path="/another" component={AnotherComponent} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

export default taskRouter;
```

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Router from './Routes';
ReactDOM.render(<Router/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Finally inside App.js

```
const App = (props) => (
  <div>
    <TopNav />
    {props.children}
    <Footer />
    <Subfooter />
  </div>
)
```

All route components will render themselves inside props.children.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks - just to clarify, would Main.js replace index.js in this case, it looks to me that it would.

Comment: Yes it will replace the index .js,you can rename that to index.js.i personally use the main. Js file which is why it's named liked that